# Where can I find files pickerresults.lib.ftl and pickerresults.lib.js in Alfresco Community v5.2.0?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

To define some extra properties for [cm:person](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml#L168) type I need `pickerresults.lib.ftl` and `pickerresults.lib.js`.

In my current installation - Alfresco Community v5.2.0 - I have not found them.

But files is available in the repository [community-edition-old](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.js).

What this could mean and what to do in this case?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find out the source files from alfresco-remote-api-5.X.jar file. 
Let me know, if you're not able to find from this jar file?

Comment: You need to modify the files and you need to place them in to the extension directory, refer here http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-webscripts.html